# Runtime Error 6 when Copying Range in excel

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I'm creating a macro to concatenate several worksheets into one. Since each worksheet has a varying number of rows, I'm trying to set it up dynamically using .end(xlDown). currently, the sub runs into a lot of errors: Initially they were object errors, and when I fixed them I got the Stack overflow Runtime Error 6. Changing variables from Integers to Long didn't fix the problem, now I just get a "400" error.

Here's the code:

```
Sub Concatenate()
    'Declare Variables
    Dim Curwb As Workbook

    'Set Variables
    Set Curwb = ActiveWorkbook

       'Concatenate Data
       'Timestamps
        Dim Stage1Count As Long
        Dim Stage2Count As Long
        Dim Stage3Count As Long
        Dim Stage4Count As Long
        Dim Stage5Count As Long
        Dim TotalCount As Long
            'Stage 1
                Curwb.Sheets("Stage 1").Select
                If Range("A3").End(xlDown).Address = Range("A3").Address Then
                    Range("A3").Copy Destination:=Curwb.Sheets _
("CombinedData").Range("A3")
                Else
                Range("A3", Range("A3").End(xlDown)).Select
                    Stage1Count = Selection.Cells.Count
                    Selection.Copy Destination:=Curwb.Sheets _
("Combined Data").Range("A3")
                End If
            'Stage 2
                Curwb.Sheets("Stage 2").Select
                If Range("A3").End(xlDown).Address = Range("A3").Address Then
                    Range("A3").Copy Destination:=Curwb.Sheets _
("Combined Data").Range("A3").Offset(Stage1Count, 0)
                Else
                Range("A3", Range("A3").End(xlDown)).Select
                    Stage2Count = Selection.Cells.Count
                    Selection.Copy Destination:=Curwb.Sheets _
("Combined Data").Range("A3").Offset(Stage1Count, 0)
                End If
End Sub
```

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

A few things to help:

1) Avoid using `.Select`, `ActiveWorkbook`, `ActiveSheet` etc.

2) Instead of using `.End(xlDown)`, if you go to last row and use `.End(xlUp)` it will get your last used row much more effectively.

3) It's also easier to work with sheets that have been declared as variables.

I've made the adjustments to your code, which shortened it quite a bit and should allow you to accomplish what you are after.

```
Sub Concatenate()

'Declare Variables
Dim Curwb As Workbook

'Set Variables
Set Curwb = Workbooks("NameOfWorkbook") 'Avoid ActiveWorkbook at all cost :)

Dim ws As Worksheet, wsCopyTo As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range

With Curwb

    Set ws = .Sheets("Stage 1")
    Set wsCopyTo = .Sheets("Combined Data")

    With ws

        Set rng = .Range(.Range("A3"), .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        rng.Copy wsCopyTo.Range("A" & wsCopyTo.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

    End With

    Set ws = .Sheets("Stage 2")
    With ws

        Set rng = .Range(.Range("A3"), .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        rng.Copy wsCopyTo.Range("A" & wsCopyTo.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

    End With

End Sub
```